# Duplicates on Saved Transaction Search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm searching over transactions with the following criteria:

Type is Transfer Order
Internal ID is 547871
Main Line is false
Tax Line is false
Shipping Line is false
COGS Line is false

I just have one results column, which is Quantity.

So I'm just looking at a single Transfer Order, and it happens to only have a single item on it, but that item is showing up three times, with different quantities each time.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k9id.png) is the results page.
What is going on here?

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement Main Line should be set to true. If you will try using mainline is true then you will not get duplicate lines.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to add following condition in the search:

```
Transaction Line Type = Item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try "transfer order quantity received" is not empty and main line is false.
This way it will eliminate the duplicate lines & show only the actual line item from TO.